# Could not deduce error when using type constraints

Tags: haskell, linear-algebra

I am using Haskell to implement a linear algebra example. However, I run into a problem when declaring the `magnitude` function.

My implementation is as follows:

```
magnitude :: (Foldable t, Functor t, Floating a) => t a -> a
magnitude = sqrt $ Data.Foldable.foldr1 (+) $ fmap (^2)
```

The idea is that `magnitude` will accept `Vec2D`, `Vec3D`, or `Vec4D`, and return the square root of the sum of the squares of their components.

Each of the three vector types implements `Functor` and `Foldable`. For example,

```
newtype Vec2D = Vec2D (a, a) deriving (Eq, Show)
instance Functor Vec2D where
    fmap f (Vec2D (x, y)) = Vec2D (f x, f y)
instance Foldable Vec2D where
    foldr f b (Vec2D (x, y)) = f x $ f y b
```

However, I receive a multitude of errors:

```
LinearAlgebra.hs:9:13:
    Could not deduce (Floating (t a -> a)) arising from a use of `sqrt'
    from the context (Foldable t, Functor t, Floating a)
      bound by the type signature for
                 magnitude :: (Foldable t, Functor t, Floating a) => t a -> a
      at LinearAlgebra.hs:8:14-60
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Floating (t a -> a))
    In the expression: sqrt
    In the expression: sqrt $ Data.Foldable.foldr1 (+) $ fmap (^ 2)
    In an equation for `magnitude':
        magnitude = sqrt $ Data.Foldable.foldr1 (+) $ fmap (^ 2)

LinearAlgebra.hs:9:20:
    Could not deduce (Foldable ((->) (t a -> a)))
      arising from a use of `Data.Foldable.foldr1'
    from the context (Foldable t, Functor t, Floating a)
      bound by the type signature for
                 magnitude :: (Foldable t, Functor t, Floating a) => t a -> a
      at LinearAlgebra.hs:8:14-60
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for (Foldable ((->) (t a -> a)))
    In the expression: Data.Foldable.foldr1 (+)
    In the second argument of `($)', namely
      `Data.Foldable.foldr1 (+) $ fmap (^ 2)'
    In the expression: sqrt $ Data.Foldable.foldr1 (+) $ fmap (^ 2)

LinearAlgebra.hs:9:41:
    Could not deduce (Num (t a -> a)) arising from a use of `+'
    from the context (Foldable t, Functor t, Floating a)
      bound by the type signature for
                 magnitude :: (Foldable t, Functor t, Floating a) => t a -> a
      at LinearAlgebra.hs:8:14-60
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num (t a -> a))
    In the first argument of `Data.Foldable.foldr1', namely `(+)'
    In the expression: Data.Foldable.foldr1 (+)
    In the second argument of `($)', namely
      `Data.Foldable.foldr1 (+) $ fmap (^ 2)'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I'm not entirely comfortable with `Functor` or `Foldable` yet - and I believe this is the indirect reason for the errors.

Can someone explain to me what the error messages are pointing at?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You ought to combine your functions into a pipeline with `(.)` not `($)`. This error is occurring because, for instance, `Data.Foldable.foldr1 (+)` expects to be applied to a `Foldable` type like `[a]` but you're actually applying it directly to `fmap (^2)` which is a function.

```
magnitude :: (Foldable t, Functor t, Floating a) => t a -> a
magnitude = sqrt . Data.Foldable.foldr1 (+) . fmap (^2)
```

or

```
magnitude :: (Foldable t, Functor t, Floating a) => t a -> a
magnitude ta = sqrt $ Data.Foldable.foldr1 (+) $ fmap (^2) $ ta
```

both will do better.

Comment: Style nitpick: I wouldn't put the last `$` in your second version, as it's redundant and makes the line more noisy.

Comment: Agreed, but it follows the pattern completely.